# Best practice for getter of native / computed properties

Tags: api, language-agnostic, naming-conventions, getter, getter-setter

This is a general question about getters.

Let's assume I have a `User` class with 2 native properties `firstname` and `lastname` and one dynamic computed property `fullname`.

What's the best way of naming the getter for those?

I'm fine with:

```
user->get_firstname();
user->get_lastname();
// or
user->firstname;
user->lastname;
```

but I'm more concerned about:

```
user->get_fullname();
// or
user->fullname;
```

because we feel like it's just another native property but it's not. The `fullname` property can be read but not written, there's no setter for it. We cannot manipulate it as if it's a native property.

I would like to be able to make a difference between those properties (native vs computed dynamically), how should I do?

Examples from existing framework and how they deal with this is more than welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say it should be named the same as the other getters. Whether it's a basic property or a calculated value comes down to implementaion specifics which I would want abstracted from the end user. Fullname might be a calculated value today but maybe in the future it won't be. I want to have the freedom to change this in future in one place but keep the public interface the same.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your question exactly is.

But you don't need to make setters for fields, where you not want to have them.
Let me make a C# example:

```
public String fullname { get; set; }
public String lastname { get; }
```

This would work.